# Un-upvote followed by re-upvote = -10 reputation bug

Tags: support, reputation, voting

This is a re-hash of a [question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2537/5764) on [Meta.TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) that seems to have grown stale...

I received an un-upvote immediately followed by a "re-upvote". To me this means that the user experimented with the voting system, thinking that they could add another upvote after my answer was updated, or the site loading caused them to prematurely click/upvote when they've already done so in the past. Either way, here's a visual:

[image]

and here's a per-time view:

[image]

The total reputation for the day should be 230 (200 + 2 accepted answers @ 15 reputation) However, the reputation tally for this day is short by the "un-upvote count" of 10. Un-upvote/re-upvote happened 1 second apart.

This is clearly a bug. Why does an "un-upvote" followed by a re-upvote count as -10 reputation rather than 0?

Comment: The un-upvote is *unrelated* to the other upvote. It is subtracted on the day the vote was cast, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So the un-upvote is *removed* from a previous day. Okay. So I'm 10 rep short *that* day. Why am I then still 10 rep short *today*? That seems to be the same discussion followed in the comments of the linked post. Plainly put, it doesn't really make sense. I still feel this is a [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @Werner: just the *display* of the un-upvote is put on the day the un-upvote took place. The original day *display* is also unaffected. If you changed this to be displayed just on the day the vote was first cast, you'd probably miss it and never learn why you lost 10 points.

Comment: @Werner: so if you gained 10 points 5 days ago from this upvote, for your reputation calculations the un-upvote was subtracted again *that day*. But for *display purposes* it is shown subtracted from today's total instead. This is important for when you hit the reputation cap as well, for example.

Comment: No, it is *by design*, not a bug. You still hit the rep cap today with the upvotes. You didn't hit the rep cap the day you got this upvote in the first place, so you do lose the 10 points that day.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm seeing the light at the end of the tunnel...

Comment: Now, if you had hit the rep cap that day too, the lost +10 could be compensated with a later upvote that day that would have been capped. Say you got 21 upvotes that day, you now only have 20 upvotes. Today's log would show a '0 unupvote' entry instead.

Comment: It works both ways. As far as I have seen, a net +10 is actually more common than a net -10. Especially for people who have most of their over-the-cap votes concentrated on a small number of days.